# Batch. How should i use GEQ and LEQ in a if-and statement?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

so I've tryed to make a simple program, so I can simulate a D20 dice roll and send a messenge (Getroffen), if the rolled number is between 10 and 15. But it just gives me a "Daneben" when the number is greater than 15. I would like to get a "Daneben" when it's less than 10 too, but that's not the case. What should I do instead?

```
 @echo off

:run
cls
echo Zahl zwischen 1 und 20
call :roll20
set zahl=%roll%
echo      %zahl%
if %zahl% GEQ 10 if %zahl% LEQ 15 (echo Getroffen) ELSE (echo Daneben)
pause >NUL
goto run

:roll20
set roll=%random%
if %roll% GTR 20 goto roll20
if %roll% LSS 1 goto roll20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only testing for `zahl` over 9, so won't get output otherwise.

```
if %zahl% GEQ 10 if %zahl% LEQ 15 (echo Getroffen) ELSE (echo Daneben)
```

The simplest solution is to use multiple tests:

```
:: values under 10
if %zahl% LSS 10 echo Daneben

:: values 10 and over but under 15
if %zahl% GEQ 10 if %zahl% LEQ 15 echo Getroffen

:: values over 15
if %zahl% GTR 15 echo Daneben
```

You should also change your randomizer to use this instead:

```
SET /a roll=(%RANDOM%*20/32768)+1
```

This performs a little math on the results of `%RANDOM%` to ensure the output value is always between 1 and 20.

Comment: Jup, I'm gonna try it out. Thank you